Rails | Foreign Key Constraint On Unique Column Other Than ID?
I have a table of tenants. While tenants do have an id, they also have a code column that is unique and indexed as well. The code column value has the advantage of being human readable. As such, I would like to use it when creating a foreign-key constraint on various other tables. However, I haven't had much luck googling how to implement this so far.
For instance, I attempted the following in a migration for adding a new table:
class CreateApps < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :apps, id: :uuid do |t|
      ...
      t.references :tenant_code, type: :string, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :tenants }
      ...
    end
 end
end

Unfortunately, when I attempt to run this migration I get an error like this:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "fk_rails_899289dfd2" cannot be implemented DETAIL:  Key columns "tenant_code_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid.

Rails wants to append _id to whatever column name I specify here rather than just using tenant_code, and it attempts to link it to the tenants table's id column rather than the code column...
How can I get Rails to create the apps table with a tenant_code column that serves as a foreign key to the tenants table via its code column?

You don't want to use references here as it's a shortcut for defining references that follow the Rails conventions which you're breaking.
Instead just do it the good old way:
class CreateApps < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :apps do |t|
      # ...
      t.string :tenant_code, null: false, index: true
      t.foreign_key :tenants, column: :tenant_code, primary_key: :code 
      # ...
    end
  end
end


You also need to configure all your assocations. I would consider if the fuss for the natural key is worth it. You can always just have the code as an supplemental unique identifier.

Thank you! This is nearly perfect. The only problem is that the Apps table appears to still be using "tenant_code_id" as the column on the Apps table instead of just "tenant_code". Any ideas on how to fix that part of it?

Ah, yeah there doesn't seem to be be an option for that. Since you're breaking  every convention its built around it doesn't actually make much sense to use references which is just a shortcut. Just define the column and then use add_foreign_key.

That did the trick! t.string :tenant_code, null: false, index: true followed up by add_foreign_key :apps, :tenants, column: :tenant_code, primary_key: :code after the create_table block seems to have done the trick! Thanks! If you wouldn't mind updating your answer I'll go ahead and accept.
